# Encrypting an ODBC connection

Tags: sql-server, security, encryption, odbc

Situation:

- We have a **SQL Server 2008 R2 database** sitting in a data centre
- We would like to allow analysts to connect to the database and **query the data using desktop based tools** (e.g. Tableau) via ODBC. The desktop based tools do not necessarily support encryption.
- We need the data and queries to be **securely encrypted while in transit over the network**

Is there a good / reliable way to achieve this - e.g. some kind of local ODBC proxy that can then communicate with the server over an encrypted connection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using the SQL Server Native Client for ODBC, you should be able to [configure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067.aspx) it to do this for you.

Answer (score 2):

Ive had good results in stunnel when i had to convert SMTP to SSMTP on devices that did not support SSMTP natively.

http://www.stunnel.org/

I dont know what encryption MSSQL Server supports but if its not SSL you can still use stunnel on the server to decrypt the messages and serve them to another port.

This is more inspiration then an real answer ^-^